# std::stringstream equivalent for u32string?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there an equivalent to `std::stringstream` which will allow me to build a `std::u32string`? If not how could I build up a `std::u32string` from lots of variable length pieces of text consisting of `char32_t` data?

Comment: Sometimes the standard library restricts the allowable template parameters. I can't say definitivly but so far I don't see anything prohibiting using this: `std::basic_stringstream<char32_t> ss;`

Comment: @Galik, thanks that seems to work nicely.

Comment: According to the `C++11/14/17` standards it is *implementation defined* if it works for types other than `char` and `wchar_t`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `std::stringstream` is a [`typedef`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/):

```
typedef basic_stringstream<char> stringstream;
```

Therefore you can specialize the `std::basic_stringstream<T>` to your needs:

```
typedef std::basic_stringstream<char32_t> u32sstream;
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the other answers are correct, that in theory this is fine. In practice it is not always so for all functionality.

Using (some versions of?) Visual Studio, the locales do not seem to work properly for char16_t and char32_t character types. These are used to get the decimal and thousand separator. Hence if you try to add a number to the stream you will receive a compilation error. I know this is at least the case for the version I am using VS 2019 4.8.03752.

Comment: Indeed. I have only been able to successfully use `std::basic_stringstream<char32_t>` on linux with libstdc++. Windows with Visual Studio 2019 and MacOS with libc++ both reject the code as invalid.